# How to Automate Web Login in Website abelhas.pt using Java

Tags: java, authentication, web, automation

I am having a hard time trying to figure out the correct process for automating login for the following website: http://abelhas.pt

I have used Firefox's HttpFox plugin to discover the login form and action page url, in the generated HTML code and have found out that to perform login, I will need to post the following parameters:

```
Login=theLogin
Password=thePassword
Redirect=True
RedirectUrl=
RememberMe=false
FileId=0
```

The url to which the parameters are being passed when the user presses the submit button, is the following: "/action/login/login" (which is the one shown on the "action" attribute of the html  element)

However, when generating and posting it using the following URL:

```
http://abelhas.pt/action/login/login?Login=theLogin&Password=thePassword&Redirect=True&RedirectUrl=&RememberMe=false&FileId=0
```

(Please note that the the values of "theLogin" and "thePassword" should be replaced by a valid login and password)

I am always getting "http://abelhas.pt/Error404.aspx", meaning that the following webpage was not found...

In the past, I have already been able to successfully automate logging-in in websites such as Google, filefactory, zippyshare, Imageshack, etc..however this one seems to be playing  tricks on me...

Can someone help me understanding what is happening or what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks guys!

Gizmo

Answer (score -1):

In my vaadin application i want to redirect to a website with automatic log in. 
Now the issue is am unable to logIn through my java code which refers from
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/
Am also getting response code: 200, and unable to make use of response.
Following is the code snippet of the website to which i want to automate login

```html
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="clientLogin">
    <input type="hidden" name="__CSRFToken__" value="eac035fe0a1a64a9945e0ce798a44a52ca040b5c" /><div style="display:table-row">
    <div class="login-box">
    <strong></strong>
    <div>
        <input id="username" placeholder="Email or Username" type="text" name="luser" size="30" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="passwd" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="lpasswd" size="30" value=""></td>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign In">
    </p>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;padding: 15px;vertical-align:top">
    <div>
<!--<b>I'm an agent</b> —
 <a href="/scp/">sign in here</a>
 -->
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```